# longtblr (tabularray): forcing a \pagebreak before first natural pagebreak does not display continuation text in table footer

Tags: longtable, tabularray

Using `longtblr` from `tabularray` package, when a "forced" `\pagebreak` is inserted before the first "natural" page break in the table, the continuation text is missing from the table foot.

In the simple example below, the first and second `\pagebreak` are inserted before a natural pagebreak occurs and you can see that the continuation text "Continued on the next page" is missing from the table foot (page 1 and 2).

While, the third `\pagebreak` is inserted after the first natural page break occurs and the continutation text is correctly dispayed in the table footer on all other pages.

How can I get the continuation text correctly displayed on each page break (natural or forced) ? Is there something I'm missing ?

Thanks for your help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}{colspec = {X}, rowhead = 1}
\hline
HEAD \\ \hline
\blindtext \\ \hline
FIRST FORCED PAGEBREAK \\ \hline
\pagebreak

\blindtext \\ \hline
SECOND FORCED PAGEBREAK \\ \hline
\pagebreak

\blindtext \\ \hline
\blindtext \\ \hline
\blindtext \\ \hline
NATURAL PAGE BREAK \\ \hline
\blindtext \\ \hline
\blindtext \\ \hline
THIRD FORCED PAGEBREAK \\ \hline
\pagebreak
\blindtext \\ \hline

\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I just saw that this issue has been reported on [GitHub](https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/164)...